# How to apply paste command recursively in a script

Tags: bash, shell, paste

I have a script:

```
paste -d, <(cut fileA1 -d, -f1-6) <(cut fileB1 -d, -f7) > fileC1
```

which takes two `csv` text files `fileA1` and `fileB1`, copies the first six columns of `fileA1` and pastes them (with replacement) into the first 6 columns of `fileB1`. The output is then saved to a new file `fileC1`.

Now, I would like to extend this to n files in `folder A` (`fileA1...fileAn`) and `folder B` (`fileB1...fileBn`) and save the output to files to `folder C` (`fileC1...fileCn`). 
All input files have an equal number of rows.

I have come up with this

```
fileA1=find /path/to/folderA -name '.csv'
fileB1=find /path/to/folderB -name '.csv' 

paste -d, <(cut fileA1 -d, -f1-6) <(cut fileB1 -d, -f7) > *.csv
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that `cut` and `paste` aren't the best tools to be using to work with CSV files in the first place. They cannot correctly handle records that have comma-containing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an explicit loop. It doesn't look like you are using any feature of `find` that can't be done in-shell, so I'm going to skip it.

```
a_files=( /path/to/folderA/*.csv )
b_files=( /path/to/folderB/*.csv )
```

Next, I'm going to assume that your file names are such that the two arrays are synchronized; the first element of each go together, etc.

```
for ((i=0; i<"${#a_files[@]}"; i++)); do
    paste -d, <(cut "${a_files[i]}" -d, -f1-6) \
              <(cut "${b_files[i]}" -d, -f7-) > fileC"$i".csv
done
```

Here, I'm assuming the name of the output file can be constructed like this. (That also implies you might be able to do the same thing for the input files; the only variable here would be the range 0-n that `i` iterates over.)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @chepner . It worked with a few changes: "${a_files[@]}" changed to `"${#a_files[@]}"´ and ´(cut "${b_files[i]}" -d, -f1-7)´ changed to ´(cut "${b_files[i]}" -d, -f7-)´. Without the second change, fileC consisted of only the first 6 and 7 columns from A and B respectively.  The script processed 200 files of 300MB each in only 10 minutes!

Comment: Thanks, I've incorporated the changes into the answer; the first was a typo, and the second was due to me not reading the original code carefully.